# IL School District Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, data, united-states

In order to help our client manipulate a map to show disparities in public school course offerings in Illinois at the school district level, we’re looking for a current year vector shapefile of the school district map, exactly like what we see here:

https://www.illinoisreportcard.com/District.aspx?districtId=15016299025

The thought would be to illustrate course deserts through creating an interactive and / or static “heatmap” at the district level (technically showing only high school and unit districts, not ALL).

Can anyone help me navigate to a map of this kind? I am struggling to figure out how to find this because I’m just not that savvy with this sort of thing.

Comment: We would really need to know what software you're using.. do you have software or is that your first consideration? is this a static map or online resource? What have you tried so far, or are you stuck on the first step?

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend.

Looks like Chicago calls those "Community Areas".
You can download the shapefile from their Data Portal at https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-Community-Areas-current-/cauq-8yn6. Just click on the blue export button in the top-right corner.
To get the exact representation as what you linked to, you'll need to just dissolve the boundaries.